# Tapermonkey url de actualizacion introducir varias

Tags: javascript

Quiero saber si puedo agregar varias URL DE ACTUALIZACION en Tapermonkey 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bien ya lo solucione, @match seguir agregando y de tal forma actua en las paginas ingresadas.

Comment: Estaria bueno q comentaras como fue la solucion asi los q entran con el mismo problema lo ven.

Comment: despues de mi post puse la respuesta... al mismo script en los comentarios agregar @match y las url en la que deseen de tal forma carga..